# OpCache not caching

Tags: opcache

ive recently activated opcache but it doesn't appear to be working.
It's confirmed activated via phpinfo()

[image]

As you can see 
0 hits
1 miss
1 cached script (opcached gui)

What am I missing?

Server is a Linux server centos 6.5 vps 
PHP 5.5

A bit more info about opcache configuration

opcache_enabled true

cache_full  false

restart_pending false

restart_in_progress false

used_memory 8.54 MB

free_memory 503.46 MB

wasted_memory   0 bytes

current_wasted_percentage   0.00%

buffer_size 4194304

used_memory 446.41 kB

free_memory 3.56 MB

number_of_strings   4895

num_cached_scripts  1

num_cached_keys 1

max_cached_keys 65407

hits    0

start_time  Sat, 26 Jul 14 23:20:32 +0000

last_restart_time   never

oom_restarts    0

hash_restarts   0

manual_restarts 0

misses  1

blacklist_misses    0

blacklist_miss_ratio    0.00%

opcache_hit_rate    0.00%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are using cgi rather than **mod_php5**.  The shared memory area (SMA) is used for both, but it only persists request-to-request for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on a WHM/cPanel server today. As TerryE suggests, you are probably running CGI or suPHP. Change to DSO.

Comment: Thanks, it was intact suphp, changing to DSO did the trick. Upvoted